# How to remove one property from json input message using replace() expression in azure logic app?

Tags: json, azure, azure-logic-apps

```
{
  "metadata": {
    "id": "2",
    "uri": "3",
    "type": "2"
  },
  "Number": "2323600002913",
  "Date": "04/21/2009",
  "postingDate": "00/00/0000",
  "ata": {
    "results": [
      {
        "metadata": {
          "id": "r",
          "uri": "e2",
          "type": "s2"
        },

        "item": "000010",
        "data":"ad"

      }
    ]
  }
}
```

want to remove `metadata` property from above json message and output should be like below

```
{
  "Number": "2323600002913",
  "Date": "04/21/2009",
  "postingDate": "00/00/0000",
  "ata": {
    "results": [
      {

        "item": "000010",
        "data":"ad"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I tried with `removeProperty()` which is working for root level `metadata` but inside `metadata` not removed.

how to use replace() in this case or anything else to only remove `metadata`.

Comment: try removing "ata.results.metadata" too!  removeProperty(json, "ata.results.metadata");

Answer (score 5):

The simplest way is use inline code, cause even with `removeProperty()` expression to remove the metadata under results, it will return the results array data not the whole json data. Then you will have to combine them, it's not a convenient way.

And with inline code you could refer to my below picture. The variable `json` is the value from triggerbody, then just delete the node or key and return the json variable. And with this way, even you want to delete many metadata in the array, you could add a for loop to delete it, just think of it as plain js code.

[image]

[image]

**Update**:if you want to get value from variable,cause no support expression to get value from variable so use the below expression.

```
var json =wworkflowContext.actions.Initialize_variable.inputs.variables[0].value;
```

And about how to loop the array in the json refer to my below pic.

[image]

Comment: thanks how to read value from a variable ? or from forloop current item?
workflowContext.actions["my.action.name"].body

Comment: @Neo, I have update the answer, check it  and if this could help you, please accept it as the answer.