# How to remove section in JSON in LogicApp

Tags: azure-logic-apps

[image]

Compose - removeProperty(variables('Message')['Appointment'],'CustomerInfo')

[image]

What I want to see if the following.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, I have initialized variable and then used compose action with `removeproperty(variables('emo')['appointment'],'customerInfo')` as below:

[image]

Then I again used compose as below with `removeproperty(variables('emo'),'appointment')`:

[image]

Then I used Compose 3 for combing both composes as below using `union(outputs('Compose_2'),outputs('Compose'))` :

[image]

Output:

[image]

[image]

**OR:**
If you have integrated account [Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59030083/how-to-remove-one-property-from-json-input-message-using-replace-expression-in). Hope this clears all your doubts.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to recreate your issue without drama and unfortunately, I couldn't find a way to use the `removeProperty` function to make it work.

You have to call the function at the level it expects so it can remove a single named property and therefore, it only returns the level the function is called at which is, obviously, a problem.

This may not be the approach for you but to overcome this shortcoming, I used the inline Javascript action to do the work.

[image: Flow]

If you've never used the action before, you need to make sure set you flow up to use an **Integration account**.  You can get one in the free tier so it doesn't cost you anything but may be limiting depending on the workload AND it's not supported for production workloads.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-enterprise-integration-create-integration-account?tabs=azure-portal%2Cconsumption

This did give me the desired outcome though ...

[image: Result]