# Remove field from a body In Azure Logic Apps

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

```
[
  {
    "@odata.etag": "",
    "ItemInternalId": "bf73ba98-d392-424c-9dc1-f2be44e9d431",
    "Name": "Shuvendu",
    "Dept": "Developer"
  },
  {
    "@odata.etag": "",
    "ItemInternalId": "3de1725d-d7cb-45fa-9855-713bbf8fdc23",
    "Name": "Debashish",
    "Dept": "DBA"
  }
]
```

This is my request body i want ro ignore `"@odata.etag"` and
`"ItemInternalId"` from the next operation in logic app I mean to say whatever the field like "Name","Dept" like this these field will be increase dynamically whatever the new field added those are needed but i want to ignore above those field

`body('List_rows_present_in_a_table')?['value']` this is the body above arrey is the body element
expecting output

```
[
  {
    "Name": "Shuvendu",
    "Dept": "Developer"
  },
  {
    "Name": "Debashish",
    "Dept": "DBA"
  }
]
```

my main intention to remove those field dynamically so whatever the input body that contain `"@odata.etag"` and `"ItemInternalId"` thesse should be removed and display rest as output
i want this functionality in azure logic apps

`body('List_rows_present_in_a_table')?['value']` this is the body from the above action [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/35q0O.png)

```
[
  {
    "Name": "Shuvendu",
    "Dept": "Developer"
  },
  {
    "Name": "Debashish",
    "Dept": "DBA"
  }
]
```

expecting this output

Answer (score 0):

***I have achieved your requirement in the following way-***

[image]

**Schema:**

```
{
"items": {
"properties": {
"@@odata.etag": {
"type": "string"
},
"Dept": {
"type": "string"
},
"ItemInternalId": {
"type": "string"
},
"Name": {
"type": "string"
}
},
"required": [
"@@odata.etag",
"ItemInternalId",
"Name",
"Dept"
],
"type": "object"
},
"type": "array"
}
```

[image]

Getting the output as below-

[image]
[image]
[image]

You need to **Parse_JSON** before performing **Compose** action in order to get the individual property value from a json.

Comment: I have two table in excel from where i am trying to converting to csv this work for first iteration its works fine suppose there are diffrent field or n numbers of field in a table so in this case what we can do . do u know any function that removes a field from a json data .

Comment: There is no function as such but you can write a Javascript code in the workflow like given in this SO thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59030083/how-to-remove-one-property-from-json-input-message-using-replace-expression-in

Comment: @SHUVENDYU how are you fetching rows from multiple table? I believe we can get rows from a single table at once

Answer (score 0):

Try using removeProperty expression

```
removeProperty(json('{ "firstName": "Sophia", "middleName": "Anne", "surName": "Owen" }'), 'middleName')
```

original json:

```
{
   "firstName": "Sophia",
   "middleName": "Anne",
   "surName": "Owen"
}
```

updated json:

```
{
   "firstName": "Sophia",
   "surName": "Owen"
}
```

more info and examples here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/workflow-definition-language-functions-reference#removeProperty

Answer (score 0):

You could do it a couple of other ways if you're interested.  One of which is the `Select` operation.

#### Select

Using a `Select` operation from the set of `Data Operations` actions, you can pick out what you want from the entire array without needing to add all of the operations for looping.

**Flow**

[image: Flow]

**Step Definition**

```
{
    "inputs": {
        "from": "@variables('Data')",
        "select": {
            "Dept": "@item()?['Dept']",
            "Name": "@item()?['Name']"
        }
    }
}
```

**Result**

[image: Result]

Depending on how dynamic your JSON could be, this may not be the best option because if a new field comes in, it will need to be mapped.

If you wanted to take it a step further, the `Advanced Data Operations` connector will do it for you without looping and dynamically selecting the relevant fields.  The structure could change and the logic will make sure the new fields are included.